# Is there any benefit to stepping on bugs?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've noticed as my burly man-hero trots around Sanctuary he has the tendency to mash lesser critters under his magically embued footwear.  There seems a very large number of snakes, scorpions, small spiders, and similar vermin that are affected in this way.  Is this just sort of a mini-easter egg, or is there a benefit to do it?  I could easily focus on more squashing if there is a reason to.

Comment: As my fiancée puts it, they make an awesome squish sound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, benefits, no achievements,nothing.
It's just a "bonus" that was present also in the previous game (I don't remember if it was in the first Diablo too).

As Sorean said, "they make an awesome squish sound".

Comment: I was secretly hoping there was a hidden achievement, but sadly no cake :(

Comment: @IvoFlipse yeah, me too, but unless it's a "Kill 10,000,000 bugs by stepping on them" hidden Feat of Strength that nobody has yet found, there don't seem to be any

Comment: I vaguely remembered some reason to step on a bunch previously.  But as usual my mind is muddled with Torchlight, so it may not have been Diablo at all.  Or I completely fabricated it in my mind :)

Comment: They should do a "Step on one of every critter type" achievement, then hide some of the rarer critters :)